# How to import a chart from one Google Sheet in another + automatically updatable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have sheet A and another, B. In A exist a chart that is continue populating with data. I want to copy it in sheet B and not with a simple copy/paste but with automatically update function.

Unfortunately I'm poor in code writing but I tried to find a solution on forums. Just one that I found: my task can get done with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the method `copy()` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String)), you can make a copy of a spreadsheet that will automatically update whenever there will be a change in the original spreadsheet.

e.g.

```
//open Spreadsheet A by Id
var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_of_Spreadsheet_A');
//Copy Spreadsheet A and call the copy Spreadsheet B
sheetA.copy("Spreadsheet B");
```